# How to download files using cloudinary API?

Tags: python, cloudinary

I was trying to make a program that would synchronize `.txt` files with Cloudinary. The purpose is to use Heroku to run the code and download the asserts back when the dyno gets restarted. The problem is that It seems that there is no download function stated on their website (most likely that is me not knowing how to read).

I think `fetch` function might be what I'm looking for, but it seems to be used for uploading as well. I also know that there is some function (maybe not from Cloudinary) that can download using the link. This solution would be fine as well, but I need to get a way to get the link then (but I'm pretty sure it gets `return`ed when you upload), the problem is, though, that my program should synchronize first which means that there is no way for me to get the link as a return value. I also wonder if there is a way to delete files (if they are not automatically replaced if they have the same name).

I have made a little sample, which can upload the file and it works well:

```
import cloudinary
import os
from cloudinary import uploader
from signal import signal, SIGINT, SIGTERM
import time

cloudinary.config(
  cloud_name = 'not_real',  
  api_key = '696969696996',  
  api_secret = 'helloWorld'  
)

def downloader():
  #something here...
  pass

downloader()

def handler(sig, frame):
  print(cloudinary.uploader.upload("TEST.txt", resource_type = "raw", public_id = "TEST"))

print("PID: ", os.getpid())
signal(SIGTERM, handler)   # to understand when the dyno is getting killed

while True:
  print("Doing nothing...")
  time.sleep(3600)
```

Once again (in short) what I would like this to do:

1. Download file either by link or name.
2. Delete the old file (if this is necessary)

Any help would be much appreciated.

upd: It seems that the link which goes to Cloudinaty `.txt` files opens an empty webpage with only text present, so I guess I can do

```
r = requests.get("https://res.cloudinary.com/name/raw/upload/v1589215899/TEST.txt")
print(r.text)
```

, but I wonder if there is a better solution.

Comment: Are you planning to store that file in your server or where will it be stored?

Comment: @daniel-mendoza, the idea is to store files on Cloudinary. But when the program is running I will download them to reduce the number of API calls. The most important thing here is how do I get the link when I first download? I don't want to enter it manually every time.

Comment: When you upload the file to Cloudinary, you will be given back the details to access that content again. Is this not being stored anywhere? I might be misunderstanding what you mean by `how do I get the link when I first download?`

Comment: @daniel-mendoza The problem was that I could only get the link when I upload something, but what if I don't? Asking for the manual link input is absurd, but necessary because Heroku stores nothing after the restart. What I found was that you can actually generate the link like this: ```link = cloudinary.utils.cloudinary_url(filename, resource_type = "raw")[0]```. That works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a `raw` upload to Cloudinary, a response is returned that includes the following:

```
{
  "public_id": "sample.txt",
  "version": 1371928603,
  "signature": "9088291a2c12202767cfa7c5e874afee72be78cd",
  "resource_type": "raw",
  "created_at": "2017-06-22T19:16:43Z",
  "tags": [],
  "bytes": 6144,
  "type": "upload",
  "etag": "107bf134b5afd11cc7544d60108d87b", 
  "url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/raw/upload/v1371928603/sample.txt",
  "secure_url": 
         "https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/raw/upload/v1371928603/sample.txt"
  "original_filename": "myoriginaltextfile"
}
```

Cloudinary recommends storing the `public_id`, `resource_type`, `type` and `version` (which can be omitted) so you can regenerate the Cloudinary URL later on. The `public_id` is the unique identifier of the asset. `resource_type` identifies what resource it is, e.g. `image`, `video`, or `raw`. `type` is the [delivery type](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#delivery_types) of that asset, e.g. `upload` (means public), `private`, and `authenticated` to name a few. `version` is the timestamp of when the asset was uploaded. With that being said, once you have those asset details, you can generate the Cloudinary URL by either doing a direct URL build or generate an image or video tag. The image/video tag wouldn't be helpful for raw files, so direct URL building would be the way to go. Cloudinary Python SDK (and any of their other SDKs) have similar functions, but the Python one can be found [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/django_image_manipulation#direct_url_building).

```
cloudinary.utils.cloudinary_url("sample.txt", resource_type = "raw")
# Output: "https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/raw/upload/sample.txt"
```